# In Matplotlib, is there a way to know the list of available output format

Tags: python, matplotlib

According to Matplotlib documentation, `matplotlib.figure.save_fig`takes an optional argument `format` (see [matplotlib.figure documentation](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.savefig)).

This parameters takes 'one of the file extensions supported by the active backend' (as said by the official documentation).

My point is: how to know, for a specific backend, the list of supported extensions?

The list of available backends is accessible thru `matplotlib.rcsetup.all_backends`. These backends are available in `matplotlib.backends` but, I do not find a way to retrieve supported extensions.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you create a figure, you can get the available supported file format with the canvas object :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()

print fig.canvas.get_supported_filetypes()

>>> {
   'svgz': 'Scalable Vector Graphics', 
   'ps': 'Postscript', 
   'emf': 'Enhanced Metafile', 
   'rgba': 'Raw RGBA bitmap',
   'raw': 'Raw RGBA bitmap',
   'pdf': 'Portable Document Format', 
   'svg': 'Scalable Vector Graphics', 
   'eps': 'Encapsulated Postscript', 
   'png': 'Portable Network Graphics' 
}
```

and it will list all the formats in which you can output your current object.

Comment: Nice one ... didn't see this canvas property on figure object.

Comment: The inscrutable magic, it burns as it heals. Thanks for this! My Matplotlib tool belt has now levelled up.

Answer (score 4):

The `FigureCanvasBase` class, located in each backends has a `get_supported_filetypes` method.

For `backend_agg`:

```
figure = matplotlib.figure.Figure()
fcb = matplotlib.backends.backend_agg.FigureCanvasBase(figure)
supported_file_types = fcb.get_supported_filetypes()
```

`supported_file_types` contains:

```
{'emf': 'Enhanced Metafile',
 'eps': 'Encapsulated Postscript',
 'pdf': 'Portable Document Format',
 'png': 'Portable Network Graphics',
 'ps': 'Postscript',
 'raw': 'Raw RGBA bitmap',
 'rgba': 'Raw RGBA bitmap',
 'svg': 'Scalable Vector Graphics',
 'svgz': 'Scalable Vector Graphics'}
```

One remaining question .... `matplotlib.get_backend()` returns `"agg"`. Is there an easier way to directly point to the correct backend module?

Comment: `matplotlib.get_backend()` is the usual way (what's not easy about that?).  if you want to change the backend, you can do it with `matplotlib.use` or setting in the matplotlibrc file, `matplotlib.matplotlib_fname()` will tell you the config file location.

Comment: `matplotlib.get_backend()` returning a raw `str` rather than the actual backend module is functionally useless for most use cases. Yes, you _can_ obviously `getattr(matplotlib.backends, 'backend_' + matplotlib.get_backend().lower())` your way to pseudo-success – **but you shouldn't have to.** Resorting to that sort of painful hackery should only ever be a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of renderers and file types: http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/faq/installing_faq.html#what-is-a-backend
Beyond that, individual backends have `get_supported_filetypes` method in their respective `FigureCanvas{backend-name}` class that gives a list of supported file formats.